# BorderBrush color won't change right away unless lost focus

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a confirm password box with `PasswordBox` control. I set the color to change to red if the password doesn't match in the event. It does change the border color after it loses focus. What I need is change the color as soon as the password is typed without losing focus. Because it is not bound to the property so I can't set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` in XAML. Here is the code:

```
private void Confirm_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            

        if(MiscParameterViewModel.servServiceLoginType == ServiceLoginTypes.Windows)
        {
            if(!string.Equals(PasswordAgainBox.Password, MiscParameterViewModel.password))
            {
                PasswordAgainBox.BorderBrush=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip toolTip = new System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip();
                toolTip.Content = "Passwords don't match!";
                ToolTipService.SetToolTip(PasswordAgainBox, toolTip);
                MiscParameterViewModel.nextButtonIsEnabled = false;


            }                
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And when you do this?

`<Border x:Name ="PwBoxBorder"  BorderThickness="1" >
     <PasswordBox KeyDown="PwBox_OnKeyDown"  />
 </Border>`

And in the event you set the color of PwBoxBorder.

Comment: Tried it and it is still the same. It is strange that the tooltip applies right a way but not the border color.

Comment: Actually it works. I had to set the color to PwBoxBorder not the passwordbox.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `KeyDown` event instead `PasswordChanged`